# Reactjs handleChange with Changing subdata in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

There is a classic handle Change function. I can change the data in the same directory. There is no problem. but I have sub-data. I can't change them. I want to handle this as clean without typing the extra functions in handlechange. How can I do it?

My state:

```
 this.state = {
            formData: {
                appointedBroker: '',
                propertyInformations: {
                    rent: false,
                    property: {
                        housing: false,
                    },
                    features: {
                        rooms: ""
                    },
                    location: ""
                },
            }
        }
```

my handleChange Function:

```
 handleChange(event) {
        const { formData } = this.state;
        formData[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ formData });
    }
```

and my inputs

```
        <TextField
            value={propertyInformations.features.rooms}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
            id="rooms"
            name={'rooms'}
            type={'text'}
            label={t('Rooms')} />
```

in this case, I just changed "appointedBroker" data
For example; I want to change "rooms"

Comment: Flatten your data, remove the nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handleChange` function, you are `directly mutating the state` which goes against the `React` pattern. Doing this way, will make the update undetected e.g by `componentDidUpdate`.

The recommended way would be something along this lines:

```
handleChange(event) {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
          formData: {
            ...prevState.formData ,
            [prevState.formData.propertyInformations.features.rooms]: e.target.value,
          },
         }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the code in handleChange should be like this

```
const updatedFormData = {...this.state.formData,
   propertyInformations : {
       ...this.state.formData.propertyInformations,
       property: {
           ...this.state.formData.propertyInformations.property,
           rooms: e.target.value
}}}

this.setState({ formData: updatedFormData })
```